# Save bfloat16 as binary format

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

What is the idiomatic way of saving a `bfloat` `torch.tensor` to disk as raw binary? Below code will throw error since numpy doesn't support `bfloat16`.

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

tensor = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).bfloat16()

# TypeError: Got unsupported ScalarType BFloat16
arr = tensor.numpy()
arr.tofile("output.bin")
```

Comment: `torch` blog notes imply you should be  able cast it to `float32` or 'view' it as `unsigned 16-bit integer`.  But then you must be more familiar with these ` torch` formats and operations than I.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that in Python any object can be serialized, you can simply register your arr object with Python's pickile.

`import pickle` 

 `with open(""output.bin", "wb") as me:`

`pickle.dump(arr, me)`